# What is the meaning of the ` cya` and `gng`?

Tags: word-meaning, slang

When I chat with a India friend in the Colloquy.
He said to me:

> ok dude i am gng out cya and all the best..

I don't understand the `gng` and `cya`, I know it should be a shorten statements. But I don't know what is that.

Comment: Could you suppose what they mean by trying to say them as written?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can probably find a definition for *cya* online.  Here's [Wiktionary's](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cya), for example:

> *(Internet slang) Alternative spelling of* [**see ya**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/see_ya#English)

But *gng* might be harder to find.  It's a simple non-standard abbreviation of *going*, created by removing the vowel letters.

---

With full spelling and punctuation, your message might look something like this:

> Okay, dude.  I am going out.  See you and all the best.

It's a simple farewell message.  *See you (later)* is a way of saying goodbye, and they were saying goodbye because they were going somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

There are various abbreviations, substitutions, and acronyms that have become common first with instant messaging and later with texting, in order to send texts more quickly without having to type as many letters.  It's a *very* long list and constantly changing, but for example:

> LOL = "laughing out loud"
>
> OMG = "oh my god",
>
> substituting 4 in place of "for" (4ever),
>
> 2 in place of "to" or "too" (me 2)
>
> 8 in place of "ate" (l8r)
>
> r in place of "are" and u in place of "you" (r u coming?)
>
> c in place of "see" (I c u)

The easiest way to figure these out is from context.  You know it's either an abbreviation for something, or a substitution for something.

"CYA", spoken out loud, sounds like "See ya", short for "see you later".  "GNG" sounds like an acronym (Got No G?) but apparently it's just short for "going".

If you're curious there are many websites with lists of common English texting slang.